# How is right to write a bold links?

Tags: html

What is the difference between

```
<a href="#"><strong>link</strong></a>
```

and

```
<strong><a href="#">link</a></strong>?
```

Which example is semantic correct?

Comment: Both are semantically valid, as long as your `<a>` element remains an inline element.

Answer (score 1):

Both are semantically correct since both belong to [**Flow content**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content-1)

For checking if the nesting of tags are semantically valid you can check the below image, although most of the time the browsers ignore the semantics and render the DOM.

[**MDN Reference**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

using css would be the better approach

```
<style>
    a.boldtext{font-weight:bold;}
 /* a{font-weight:bold;}   this would apply to all links */
</style>

<a class="boldtext" href="#">link</a>
```

Comment: the whole meaning of using a semantic strong tag would be ignored by doing this. strong tag has a meaning, if it was just a styling issue your answer could be correct.